# which conjunction should be used in a negative clause: "and" or "or"?

Tags: conjunctions, coordination

To say that I don't have something and something else, should I say: "I don't have a white shirt AND black trousers."or "I don't have a white shirt OR black trousers."

Comment: **And** means you have *both* shirt and trousers. **Or** means you have *only* one of them.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul That isn't what the OP is asking! They do not have either garment, so it should be "I don't have a white shirt OR black trousers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either, but they mean slightly different things:

With a negative clause, "and" means you are applying the negative to both things together as a single unit, while "or" means you're talking about each thing individually and applying the negative to each one.  So:

> I don't have a white shirt **and** black trousers.

This means that you don't have the combination of a white shirt and black trousers.  You might have just a white shirt, or just black trousers, but not both (or you might have neither).

> I don't have a white shirt **or** black trousers.

This is the same as saying "I don't have a white shirt.  I don't have black trousers."  It means that you don't have a white shirt (at all), and you also don't have black trousers (at all).  So what this really means is you have neither.